# Reading file path works well on Android Simulator but not on actual Device

Tags: android, plugins

I've written a plugin that will access the filebrowser so the user can pick one file. When I test my apk in my Genymotion simulator (Android 6.0 onwards), after allowing the permissions, once i selected my apk, i get the proper filepath (/sdcard/emulator/0/demo.apk) but when I run it on my device, i get a different filepath, something like /document/6133-6330:Download/demo.apk. Now, I know the two devices have different path but I'm getting a path with a colon instead of a slash in the latter one. Also, it's different from the file path that i see in when i manually check the location of the object.

Comment: what do you need a path for? use `InputStream` instead

Comment: @pskink i need the path of the file because I will use it to upload it to my server. does inputstream work of apks?

Comment: how do you want to upload it? using `URLConnection` or some third party libs? if so, how?

Comment: @pskink the uploading part will be done by Kii. It's settled. when i manually set the file path, the uploading works but I'm kinda stuck right now because I can't properly get the file path of the selected file. It works on the emulator. I have no idea why it doesnt work on my device running the same OS

Comment: then instead of file path find a method that uses `InputStream`

Comment: does `Kii` API accept `InputStream` ?

Comment: @pskink Kii uses this line of code to access the file to be uploaded :
  FileStream file = new FileStream("myImage.jpg", FileMode.Open);. the "myImage.jpg" should be replaced with the path of the file which is what Im trying to get